# Is there a state of matter with no definite volume but definite shape?

Tags: thermodynamics, states-of-matter, phase-diagram

Essentially I am wondering since solids have definite shape and volume, liquids have definite volume, and gases have neither definite volume or shape if there was a state of matter that can change volume but not shape.

Comment: Your title and body ask opposite questions.

Comment: But Chemomechanics has made them agree. Does the edit reflect what you meant to ask?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that liquids have no shape. Their shape can change but that doesn't mean they have none. If you put water in a jar, it takes the shape of the interior of the jar. I am not sure shape is a concept in physics. Did you mean a shape with fixed internal parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solids undergo volumetric changes all the time without changing shape: Consider a uniform solid contracting under hydrostatic pressure or expanding or contracting from a temperature change, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edit.